# Using GRect in Java with a for loop causes errors

Tags: java, for-loop, graphics

I am attempting to use Java and the [Grect class](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GRect.html) to draw a pyramid of bricks. To draw a single brick, it's fairly simple:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

/** Width of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

/** Height of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

/** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;

public void run() {


    GRect brick1 = new GRect(50, 400, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
    add(brick1);

}
```

To avoid repeating code, I want to use a for loop like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
    GRect brick[i] = new GRect(50, 400, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
    add(brick[i]);
}
```

(I realize in the above example that the bricks will draw on top of each other, I'm just trying to understand why I'm not allowed to use the for loop to do this.)

I get the following message in Eclipse:

"Multiple markers at this line
-Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
-Type mismatch: cannot convert from GRect to Grect[]
-Grect cannot be resolved to a type"

What is the proper way I should be doing this to avoid committing the sin of "Do Not Repeat Yourself"?

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the array correctly.  You're assigning a single instance of a brick to an array.  Try creating the array first outside the loop, like so.

```
GRect bricks[] = new bricks[14];

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    bricks[i] = new GRect(50, 400, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
    add(bricks[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct but you are not using java arrays properly Both syntactically and logically. You can use it for example like this:

```
GRect brick = new GRect[14]
for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
   brick[i] = new GRect(50, 400, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
   add(brick[i]);
}
```

For more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

And by the way, you are not really need arrays for this case, you just need the for loop.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that I was attempting to just use a for loop to solve this, but I accidentally put array braces instead of a pair of parenthesis ... ouch. I'm still getting errors ... I just want to have the count appear when creating each object like brick(1), brick(2), until I build the pyramid.

Comment: try this, if all you need is printing:

for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
       System.out.println("adding brick: " + i);

       add(new GRect(50, 400, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT));
}